# Networkx: Find all minimal cuts consisting of only nodes from one set in a bipartite graph

Tags: python, networkx

In the networkx python package, is there a way to find all node cuts of minimal size consisting of only nodes from one set in a bipartite graph? For example, if the two sides of a bipartite graph are A and B, how might I go about finding all minimal node cuts consisting of nodes entirely from set B? The following code I have works but it's extremely slow:

```
def get_one_sided_cuts(G, A, B):
    #get all cuts that consist of nodes exclusively from B which disconnect
    #nodes from A
    one_sided_cuts = []
    seen = []

    l = list(combinations(A, 2))

    for x in l:
        s = x[0]
        t = x[1]

        cut = connectivity.minimum_st_node_cut(G, s, t)
        if set(cut).issubset(B) and (cut not in seen):
            one_sided_cuts.append(cut)
        seen.append(cut)

    #find minimum cut size
    cur_min = float("inf")
    for i in one_sided_cuts:
        if len(i) < cur_min:
            cur_min = len(i)

    one_sided_cuts = [x for x in one_sided_cuts if len(x) == cur_min]

    return one_sided_cuts
```

Note that this actually only checks if there is a minimal cut which, if removed, would disconnect two nodes in A only. If your solution does this (instead of finding a cut that will separate *any* two nodes) that's fine too. Any ideas on how to do this more efficiently?

Comment: By "node cuts of minimal size consisting of only nodes from one set in a bipartite graph" do you mean minimal node cuts when considering only one set B of G, or minimal node cuts consisting of nodes from all of G that happen to fall into B?

Comment: Your code implies the latter. For the Graph `G = nx.Graph()` `G.add_edges_from([0,4), (0,5), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1,7), (3,6), (3,7)])` the minimal set of nodes from B gives a size 2 set:  `{6, 7}` or `{4,5}` while the minimal set is `{1}` which is in A.

Comment: Just confirming that you mean the former, otherwise your code above is not correct.

Comment: Could you translate your "Find all minimal cuts consisting of only nodes from one set in a bipartite graph" to a real "simplified" example of a graph & nodes and what you want to achieve, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comment, there are a couple of interpretations of “all node cuts of minimal size consisting of only nodes from one set in a bipartite graph”. It either means

1. All node cuts of minimum size when restricting cuts to be in one set of the bipartite graph, or
2. All node cuts in an unconstrained sense (consisting of nodes from A or B) that happen to completely lie in B.

From your code example you are interested in 2. According to the docs, there is a way to speed up this calculation, and from profile results it helps a bit. There are auxiliary structures built, per graph, to determine the minimum node cuts. Each node is replaced by 2 nodes, additional directed edges are added, etc. according to the Algorithm 9 in   http://www.cse.msu.edu/~cse835/Papers/Graph_connectivity_revised.pdf
We can reuse these structures instead of reconstructing them inside a tight loop:

Improvement for Case 2:

```
from networkx.algorithms.connectivity import (
    build_auxiliary_node_connectivity)
from networkx.algorithms.flow import build_residual_network

from networkx.algorithms.flow import edmonds_karp

def getone_sided_cuts_Case2(G, A, B):
    # build auxiliary networks
    H = build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G)
    R = build_residual_network(H, 'capacity')


    # get all cutes that consist of nodes exclusively from B which disconnet
    # nodes from A
    one_sided_cuts = []
    seen           = []

    l = list(combinations(A,2))

    for x in l:
        s = x[0]
        t = x[1]

    cut = minimum_st_node_cut(G, s, t, auxiliary=H, residual=R)
    if set(cut).issubset(B):
        if cut not in seen:
            one_sided_cuts.append(cut)
    seen.append(cut)

    # Find minimum cut size
    cur_min = float('inf')
    for i in one_sided_cuts:
        if len(i) < cur_min:
            curr_min = len(i)

    one_sided_cuts = [x for x in one_sided_cuts if len(x) == cur_min]

    return one_sided_cuts
```

For profiling purposes, you might use the following, or one of the built-in bipartite graph generators in Networkx:

```
def create_bipartite_graph(size_m, size_n, num_edges):
    G = nx.Graph()

    edge_list_0 = list(range(size_m))
    edge_list_1 = list(range(size_m,size_m+size_n))
    all_edges = []

    G.add_nodes_from(edge_list_0, bipartite=0)
    G.add_nodes_from(edge_list_1, bipartite=1)

    all_edges = list(product(edge_list_0, edge_list_1))
    num_all_edges = len(all_edges)

    edges = [all_edges[i] for i in random.sample(range(num_all_edges), num_edges)]
    G.add_edges_from(edges)

    return G, edge_list_0, edge_list_1
```

Using `%timeit`, the second version runs about 5-10% faster.

For Case 1, the logic is a little more involved. We need to consider minimal cuts from nodes only inside B. This requires a change to `minimum_st_node_cut` in the following way. Then replace all occurences of `minimum_st_node_cut` to `rest_minimum_st_node_cut` in your solution or the Case 2 solution I gave above, noting that the new function also requires specification of the sets `A`, `B`, necessarily:

```
def rest_build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G,A,B):
    directed = G.is_directed()

    H = nx.DiGraph()

    for node in A:
        H.add_node('%sA' % node, id=node)
        H.add_node('%sB' % node, id=node)
        H.add_edge('%sA' % node, '%sB' % node, capacity=1)

    for node in B:
        H.add_node('%sA' % node, id=node)
        H.add_node('%sB' % node, id=node)
        H.add_edge('%sA' % node, '%sB' % node, capacity=1)        

    edges = []
    for (source, target) in G.edges():
        edges.append(('%sB' % source, '%sA' % target))
        if not directed:
            edges.append(('%sB' % target, '%sA' % source))
    H.add_edges_from(edges, capacity=1)

    return H

def rest_minimum_st_node_cut(G, A, B, s, t, auxiliary=None, residual=None, flow_func=edmonds_karp):

    if auxiliary is None:
        H = rest_build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G, A, B)
    else:
        H = auxiliary

    if G.has_edge(s,t) or G.has_edge(t,s):
        return []
    kwargs = dict(flow_func=flow_func, residual=residual, auxiliary=H)

    for node in [x for x in A if x not in [s,t]]:
        edge = ('%sA' % node, '%sB' % node)
        num_in_edges = len(H.in_edges(edge[0]))
        H[edge[0]][edge[1]]['capacity'] = num_in_edges

    edge_cut = minimum_st_edge_cut(H, '%sB' % s, '%sA' % t,**kwargs)

    node_cut = set([n for n in [H.nodes[node]['id'] for edge in edge_cut for node in edge] if n not in A])

    return node_cut - set([s,t])
```

We then have, for example:

```
In [1]: G = nx.Graph()
        # A = [0,1,2,3], B = [4,5,6,7]
In [2]: G.add_edges_from([(0,4),(0,5),(1,6),(1,7),(4,1),(5,1),(6,3),(7,3)])
In [3]: minimum_st_node_cut(G, 0, 3)
           {1}
In [4]: rest_minimum_st_node_cut(G,A,B,0,3)
           {6, 7}
```

Finally note that the `minimum_st_edge_cut()` function returns `[]` if two nodes are adjacent. Sometimes the convention is to return a set of `n-1` nodes in this case, all nodes except the source or sink. Anyway, with the empty list convention, and since your original solution to Case 2 loops over node pairs in `A`, you will likely get `[]` as a return value for most configurations, unless no nodes in `A` are adjacent, say.

**EDIT**

The OP encountered a problem with bipartite graphs for which the sets A, B contained a mix of integers and str types. It looks to me like the `build_auxiliary_node_connectivity` converts those str nodes to integers causing collisions. I rewrote things above, I think that takes care of it. I don't see anything in the `networkx` docs about this, so either use all integer nodes or use the `rest_build_auxiliary_node_connectivity()` thing above.

Comment: It turns out I actually wanted case 1, so thanks for providing that. However, I sometimes get KeyErrors when using your code. The nodes in my set A are integers, and the nodes in my set B are two letter strings, such as 'dk', to keep the sets differentiated. When I run your code for case 1, I sometimes get errors like the following:

Comment: Line 314, in rest_minimum_st_node_cut
    H[edge[0]][edge[1]]['capacity'] = num_in_edges
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 438, in __getitem__
    return self.adj[n]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx/classes/coreviews.py", line 82, in __getitem__
    return AtlasView(self._atlas[name])
KeyError: '309A'

Comment: Any idea what's happening? I'm not used to using Digraphs in Networkx so I'm having trouble parsing the error myself.

Comment: In that case, run `H = build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G)`  and verify that there is a node '309A' in H and a node '309' in `G` and in `A`, i.e.: check `"309A" in H.nodes` and `309 in G.nodes' . If one is `False` print out the first few items of `G.nodes` and `H.nodes` here.

Comment: The digraph `H` is an auxiliary helper structure that the algorithm relies on to calculate max flow/min cut. There are 2 nodes (xxA, xxB) in `H` for every node xx in `G`. I constructed some examples along your lines and don't see your error.

Comment: It looks like when I get the KeyError, the nodes in the auxilliary graph H do not reflect the nodes in G at that time. My code removes nodes from G, so G is changing all the time. When I get the KeyError, 309 is in both G and A, but '309A' is not in H. At the time of KeyError, here are the first few items in G: ['gu', 'gr', 'xv', 'dy', 'gz', 'gy', 15, 'gd', 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39...], and in H: ['29B', '166B', '166A', '29A', '170A', '170B', '106A', '106B', '231B', '214B', '149A', '149B', '256B', '214A'...]

Comment: in `rest_minimum_st_node_cut()`, don't pass `auxiliary` into the function, let it be created inside by `H = build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G)`. That way it is tied to `G` and you shouldn't get the key error. If you are reusing H then that will cause these errors. In your example above `H` is stale.

Comment: When you take your `G` above, and issue `H = build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G)`, could you print out `H.nodes` here?

Comment: If I pass None into rest_minimum_st_node(), at the time of the KeyError after H = build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G) gets called, H.nodes() is the following: https://pastebin.com/1SxQS3TH

Comment: I would have to see the `G` that produced this `H`. The call `H = build_auxiliary_node_conectivity(G)` will create a node 'XXA' and 'XXB' for every node 'XX' in `G`.    If that is not happening, print both `G.node` and `H.node` directly after the call and post. It must be the case that the `H` comes from a different `G`. So post the `G.nodes` also if you could for the problematic case.

Comment: G.nodes() for the problematic case is the following: https://pastebin.com/kMfRZDyJ. This is a printout of G.nodes() directly after H = build_auxiliary_node_connectivity(G) is called for the problematic case, and the H.nodes() of this H is shown in the earlier pastebin link I shared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160537/discussion-between-jake-burchard-and-charles-pehlivanian).

Comment: I addressed your concern. It seems those algos in Networkx don't play well with a mix of str and integer nodes - it converts str nodes to int without regard to collisions. Please either use all integer, all str, or just the functions I include above.